# self argument not defined when calling method?

Tags: python, class, methods, self

Hi I am developing a system that is making use of the Phidget sensors and having some issues trying to write some variables to a database. I have read around a fair amount on classes and calling variables but I just cannot get this code to run.

My code is below, as you can see I have put the 'self' argument when database method is called but it is complaining 'self' is not defined. If I don't have self in there I get a complaint that 'database() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self''

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('testing.db')      
cursor = connection.cursor()

class sensors():

    def interfaceKitAttached(self, e):
        attached = e.device
        print("InterfaceKit %i Attached!" % (attached.getSerialNum()))

    def sensorInputs(self, e):



        temperature = (interfaceKit.getSensorValue(0)*0.2222 - 61.111)
        self.sound =  (16.801 * math.log((interfaceKit.getSensorValue(1))+ 9.872))
        light = (interfaceKit.getSensorValue(2))

        print("Temperature is: %i " % temperature)
        print("Sound is : %i" %self.sound)
        print("Light is: %i \n" %light)

        interfaceKit.setSensorChangeTrigger(0, 25)
        interfaceKit.setSensorChangeTrigger(1, 35)
        interfaceKit.setSensorChangeTrigger(2, 60)


    def database(self):


        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE events1
        (sensor text, value text)''')

        cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO events1 VALUES (?, ?)', ('sounding', self.sound))


        connection.commit()
        connection.close()




try:
    interfaceKit.setOnAttachHandler(interfaceKitAttached)
    interfaceKit.setOnSensorChangeHandler(sensorInputs)
    database(self)
```

Thanks

Comment: I've fixed part of the formatting issue with the code, but I'm not sure if I correctly indented the `try` block at the end. Without an `except`, a `try` clause is not legal, so I'm not sure how that's supposed to work anyway.

Comment: Apologies I thought I had copied all my code (which included the except clauses) but apparently not

Comment: It's OK, just edit the question to put the full code in (or the relevant part, at least). Make sure it comes out indented properly afterwards. The easiest way is usually to paste it in as came from your editor, then highlight it and click on the `{}` button to have Stack Overflow indent it more.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is not an argument that you pass in the parenthesis. `self` is an argument that is passed as follows:

`object.method()`

Here you are actually passing the object as an argument, `self`.

Therefore, in your case, you actually need to call the method in the form of `object.method()` where `object` is an instance of the class that your method is in. In this case, your class is `sensors`.

So you do NOT do:

`database(self)`

you do

`sensors_object = sensors()`

`sensors_object.database()`

When you call the `sensors_object = sensors()` call, you create a new `sensors` object. Then you call the OBJECT's method NOT the CLASS's method in the line that follows.

[NOTE:] I recommend that you create a `def __init__(self):` method. This is the method that gets called when you create a new instance of a class. In this `__init__` method, you initialize all the different variables that you need as `self.variable_name = something`

Comment: Apologies I assume this is actually something relatively simple but after calling my method via:

sensors.database(self)

I am getting an error of 'sensors' is not defined

Comment: @user3375667, was that helpful or is there anything else you would like to ask?